# May the first be with you

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program to replace all occurrences of "force" with "first" and all occurrences of "first" with "force", keeping the original case for all character positions:

```
"ForcefoRcefOrcE" -> "FirstfiRstfIrsT"
"FirstfiRstfIrsT" -> "ForcefoRcefOrcE"
```

The rest of the string must stay unchanged, and so running your program twice shall return the original string:

```
"thirst of forces" -> "thirst of firsts" -> "thirst of forces"
```

Your program should work on any initial string. So as a hint, you better avoid using magic characters as intermediate representation, because if you try a three pass replacement (`"force" -> "zzzzz", "first" -> "force", "zzzzz" -> "first"`), it will fail on strings containing `"zzzzz"`.

You should support the full range of characters allowed in a definition of a String by your programming language (in most cases, it's Unicode). Example, using JSON-style representation for non-printable characters (\u + 4 digits):

```
"\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003the Force of the firsT"
                     |
                     V
"\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003the First of the forcE"
```

Comment: Atta boy. Remind people that the tag has the winning criterion'

Comment: [Quite related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37480/forcing-the-horse)

Comment: Can't you just ignore the leading `f`?

Comment: @Challenger5 No I don't think so since if the leading `[Ff]` isn't there then you must not replace the word.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The OP hasn't replied to MartinEnder's comment. My submission assumes that context doesn't matter.

Comment: @Challenger5 I wasn't talking about that, but I don't think you can can replace "orce" -> "irst" instead of "force"->"first", since then you will be replacing things like "divorce" -> "divirst".

Comment: May May first be with you. (Commented on May 1st)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "May the _fourth_ be with you"?

Comment: You should've waited 3 days...

Comment: @mbomb007 "fourth" and "force" do not have the same number of letters, making it incompatible for keeping same character case.

Comment: @Cœur You meant to ping wizzwizz4 instead, huh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 33 bytes

```
iT`\OC\E\ocetsiTSI`Ro`first|force
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@58ZkhDj7xzjGpOfnFpSnBkS7JkQlJ@QlllUXFKTll@UnPr/v29ipUJJRqqCG4irkJSqUJ5ZkqFQmV8KAA)

Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder for pointing out what `Ro` does.

Comment: Yep, was going to post once the OP replies to my comment. You can save a few bytes by reordering the first set so that the second one can be `Ro`.

Comment: @MartinEnder The documentation confused me by paying too much attention to `R`'s effect on ranges; for instance I would never have realised that `RE` is equivalent to `86420` if you hadn't pointed it out.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I'll try to make that clearer in the docs.

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>93</s> 88 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/force|first/gi,s=>s.replace(/./g,c=>s[s.search(c)^1]||c,s="oicsetOICSET"))
```

```html
<textarea oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)></textarea><pre id=o>
```

Edit: Saved 5 bytes by optimising the unchanged letter case.

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 52 bytes

51 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s%first|force%$&=~y/oceOCEistIST/istISToceOCE/r%eig
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@F@smpZZVFxSk5ZflJyqqqJmW1epn5@c6u/smllc4hkcog@hIEL6Raqpmen//4dkpCq45Rc5uyokJ@amKqRlBhWHAAA)

Nothing too crazy going on. Find the occurrences of `force` and `first` non-case-sensitive (`s%force|first%%gi`), and then transliterates the characters to convert one to the other.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 88 Bytes

[Online Versions](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e93753dcfb53bde47d01c4cacfb3abaeaa1a1c6)

```
<?=preg_replace_callback("#first|force#i",function($t){return$t[0]^first^force;},$argn);
```

## PHP, 110 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace_callback("#first|force#i",function($t){return strtr($t[0],iIsStToOcCeE,oOcCeEiIsStT);},$argn);
```

Comment: You could save a few bytes with `$t[0]^first^force` instead of `strtr()`.

Comment: @user63956 Thank You for the learning effort

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 61 bytes

Requires `⎕IO←0` which is default on many systems. Can be four *characters* shorter using the Unicode symbol `⍠` instead of `⎕OPT` .

```apl
(t←'force' 'first')⎕R{(m∊⎕A)c¨t⊃⍨~t⍳(c←819⌶)⊂m←⍵.Match}⎕OPT 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#U9Z71DfV0/9R2wSD/2lAUqMESKin5Rclp6orqKdlFhWXqGsClQRVa@Q@6ugCshw1kw@tKHnU1fyod0VdyaPezRrJQC0WhpaPerZpPupqygXyHvVu1fNNLEnOqAVq8A8IUTD8/z9NQd0NbCwXiAU2GMRKyw@CiqVlBsHE/IuSXSEsz6LiEBDL3NAUZIG6UkypARCASUMwaQQmjUsyUhXA5ivkpymAOCC3hygRrxfkIrheoEGuQL0A)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>318</s> <s>310</s> <s>284</s> <s>279</s> <s>277</s> <s>271</s> 256 bytes

```java
String c(String s){var x=s.toLowerCase();int i=x.indexOf("force")+1,j=x.indexOf("first")+1,t=i>0&j>i|j<1?1:-1;var y=s.toCharArray();return-j<i?s.substring(0,i=t<0?j:i)+(y[i++]-=t*6)+y[i++]+(y[i++]+=t*16)+(y[i++]+=t*15)+c(s.length()>i?s.substring(i):""):s;}
```

-34 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hZFNb8IwDIbv/AqrhylZR0U3jQOloAltEtIQUuHGOISSDnesmRKXUTF@O2vDh8SF5mDFzuvXyZNUbEQzXX4d4rUwBkYCs10DwJAgjOEwIY3ZJ8TstDF8txEatqHxSL2rX6kHwkjGA8wIMNx6mC3ldpwwJ1E6lg53/Yf0qozakC1TiL3WXdrDv7Tr9/1O0w8q68JaD1ZCv2gtitJaS8p11ky72DeeyRfGXoW1HjCkbqufdpC7rJih686bId23uXtMzkW3LPptfpU@czdmxlvL7JNWjPeurZF3HId3TLA/BI2Sxk@@WJc0TlA2CpfwXYI6QZnNQfAKGsCkMCS/PZWT91Me0TpjMXPejih4cEtz5HJTk6io1ifBqN5nrOPXOs1Qm2mN5iNvlctG38ZHG59oJcG@GVQCVVJ9ep3ZSBQXLcFCwi/SCgqV1/RNq56hntB5mCV5mTyOBq@Xk2E0mV4SFQ1qYNbcyrbuG/vDPw)

**Explanation:**

```java
String c(String s){                     // Recursive method with String as both parameter and return-type
  var x=s.toLowerCase();                //  Temp String as lowercase of the input
  int i=x.indexOf("force")+1,           //  Index of "force" + 1 (becomes 0 if NOT present; >=1 if it is present)
      j=x.indexOf("first")+1,           //  Index of "first" + 1 (becomes 0 if NOT present; >=1 if it is present)
      t=i>0&j>i|j<1?1:-1;               //  Temp integer: -1 if "force" is found first; 1 if "first" is found first
  var y=s.toCharArray();                //  Convert the string to a character-array
  return-j<i?                           //  If either "force" or "first" is found:
    s.substring(0,i=t<0?j:i)            //   Return the substring before that (if any) + ('f' or 'F')
     +(y[i++]-=t*6)                     //   + 'i'↔'o' or 'I'↔'O'
     +y[i++]                            //   + 'r' or 'R'
     +(y[i++]+=t*16)                    //   + 's'↔'c' or 'S'↔'C'
     +(y[i++]+=t*15)                    //   + 't'↔'e' or 'T'↔'E'
     +c(s.length()>i?s.substring(i):"") //   + a recursive call for the rest of the input-String (if any)
   :                                    //  Else:
    s;}                                 //   Return the input-String as is
```

Comment: I appreciate that you provided a symmetric example `c(c("..."))`!

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks! Your character-array approach also opened up a golf for 15 more bytes due to implicit casting. :)

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 66 bytes

```
qY5m*_"force"{f{_eu}3/:z{~?}f%}:K~\"first"K.{[\]:P~@\/\f/P~@\f*\*}
```

Goes through every case variation of "first" and "force" and tries to split on it. If it can, it then joins it back with the reverse words.

Pseudocode:

```python3
input_chars = list(read_all_input()) # CJam: q
power = cartesian_power(2, 5) # CJam: Y4m*_
def case_variations(s): # CJam: {...}:K
    temp0 = [[i, j, upper(j)] for i, j in zip(power, s)] # CJam: f{_eu}3/
    temp1 = map(transpose, temp0) # CJam: :z
    ret = []
    for i in ret:
        for j in i: # CJam: {...}f%
            ret.append(j[1] if j[0] else j[2]) # CJam: ~?
    return ret
force_var = K("force") # CJam: "force"{...}:K~
first_var = K("first") # CJam: \"first"K
for force, first in zip(force_var, first_var): # CJam: .{...}
    current = [force, first] # CJam: [\]:P~
    input_chars = list_split(input_chars, force) # CJam: @\/
    input_chars = [list_split(i, first) for i in input_chars] # CJam: \f/
    input_chars = [list_join(i, force) for i in input_chars] # CJam: P~@\f*
    input_chars = list_split(input_chars, first) # CJam: \*
```

Comment: Surely the `f` is relevant to avoid changing `thirst` into `thorce` or `divorce` into `divirst`?

Comment: @Neil True, edited.

Comment: @Cœur [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@18YaZqrFa@Ull@UnKpUnVYdn1paa6xvVVVdZ1@bplpr5V0Xo5SWWVRcouStVx0dE2sVUOcQox@Tpg@i07RitGr//89NrFQoyUhVABuikJSqUJ5ZkqFQmV@q4JYZFBwCAA "CJam – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>37</s> 36 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*Is there is a way to use a reduce across slices of length 5 instead?*

```
®‘©ị“Ɓu“¡Ḣƭ»
Œlœṣ¢œṣ€¢j€¢j¢Œu⁸=ŒuT¤¦
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39o3aOGGYdWPtzd/ahhzrHGUiB5aOHDHYuOrT20m@vopJyjkx/uXHxoEZh61LTm0KIsCAkUmlT6qHGHLZAKObTk0LL///8ruWUWFZcolGSkKqSBWWn5RcmpEDJFwc0/yNlVCQA)**

#### How?

```
®‘©ị“Ɓu“¡Ḣƭ» - Link 1 helper that fetches the next word to use: no arguments
®            - recall value from register (initially zero)
 ‘           - increment
  ©          - place the result into the register
    “Ɓu“¡Ḣƭ» - literal dictionary compressed string list ["first","force"]
   ị         - index into (1-indexed and modular)
             - so this link first yields "first", then "force", then "first" and so on.

Œlœṣ¢œṣ€¢j€¢j¢Œu⁸=ŒuT¤¦ - Main link: list of characters, S
Œl                      - convert S to lower case
  œṣ                    - split on sublists equal to:
    ¢                   -   call the last link (1) as a nilad ("first")
     œṣ€                - split €ach on sublists equal to:
        ¢               -   call the last link (1) as a nilad ("force")
         j€             - join €ach with:
           ¢            -   call the last link (1) as a nilad ("first")
            j           - join with:
             ¢          -   call the last link (1) as a nilad ("force")
                      ¦ - apply a link to sparse indices:
              Œu        -   convert to upper case
                     ¤  -   nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                ⁸       -     chain's left argument, S
                  Œu    -     convert to upper case
                 =      -     equal to S? (vectorises)
                    T   -     truthy indexes (indexes at which input is upper case)
```

Comment: Pyth and Jelly are equal :o

Comment: There must be a golfier way :D

Comment: Yes, and I just found it :D

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 47 bytes

```
5W:qB!"o['first';'force']@!32*-cZ}_Zt5M_6MoZt|c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28ablXopKiUH62elllUXKJurZ6WX5Scqh7roGhspKWbHFUbH1Vi6htv5psfVVKT/P@/um9ipUJJRqqCG1Cdq0JSqkJ5ZkmGQmV@qUJ@HlgizRNokEJ@mgJQpToA)

This uses negative values as the intermediate step, and after the two passes it takes the absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
K"first"srVjJ"force"mjKcdJcr0QKqVr1
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22first%22srVjJ%22force%22mjKcdJcr0QKqVr1&input=%22The+fIrSt+of+the+First+of+the+fORCE+of+the+FIRST+of+the+FoRCe%22&debug=0)

Pyth is not especially good at string manipulations.

Comment: Yet, you were holding second place for 7 years. Now fourth place, behind Vyxal, 05AB1E and Retina.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>201</s> <s>183</s> <s>226</s> 214 bytes

Had some bugs...
Still needs to be golfed down quite a lot

(saved 12 thanks to ceilingcat)

```c
char*s,*p,*q;main(i,v)char**v;{puts(s=v[1]);do{p=strcasestr(s,"first");q=strcasestr(s,"force");if(p&&(!q|p<q))p[1]+=6,p[3]-=16,p[4]-=15;else if(q)q[1]-=6,q[3]+=16,q[4]+=15;s=p&&(!q|p<q)?p:q;}while(s++);puts(v[1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#XY6xTwMhHIX/FbyhgYMbatVBSjp5iYNL7WKaDoickFwL3I9eY2r/bFcRzsU4vZeXLy9fUkYONbDaszrwvbQHbNlIprUe@dkfI2AQ43a@I/zNnb2AOCgJOgcGVnV2gFgRHv7vblA677bDfjbDV@HTLwMhPv9Qccf8drFrxLyUm1Juue5Bo0wHEjLTZCZkhhYmZIYWBsSfr5W/D/xyMrbXGCglfFL9Fb2klKon@YGi0ah1a6XRq0YnGw16cUfkOtRm7w2SERXRh/Zx/byZqobqW3W9fIfU7BfXXwfXKKmM/gE)

Comment: [183 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY4xb8IwEEb/ismAEtsZgLYDwWIiEkMXylIhBtdySCTAPp9Jhdr@9bpnxk739L3hnqnNWV9PKZleB46Se8mhuejhWg5yrB4rH5uvzoXS3yKWqLgQY9V4hTEYjZZOibLohoCxqCT8310wlnZUfjqdwLdfwdofZkehXqQ/LI61mmV4yvAs/RLWQLYmC2RFtkBWZAtLaFAIep5LOFX8pJSKV31nsbesdTtj2Ydln0Ps2bu7Mdexlrr2TEeWQzbtdve2f6DF4td0Z33CVF8W8z8 "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7, <s>173</s> 165 bytes

8 bytes saved by quintopia

This one got gross:

```
lambda S:`[(t[0],t[0].upper())[t[1]]for t in zip("".join("first".join(s.replace("first","force")for s in S.lower().split("force"))),[l.isupper() for l in S])]`[2::5]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RY5NC8IwDIbv@xWhpxZKUcHLYEe9Cu5YCtatZZW6ljYy8M/PdijmkI@XPHmz2s7r533U0Lc3SVHuFK9JvGI0iTImUe6VsiEBgpvh7SIlRDyCmymxLmX8DlkkE70ezE/mpECDIayyubK98GGpR0WO3iH9LTDGpRcufy2hAn4DFFM3eWjbo1p76ECScyVsuJZ0ScOpmOBU3SBY2K5lwmHTRkBT9EFnA4vDKbwQTKkmwRLSSFTz/6ttoERMbkawNDNe9K4rbR3Y@gE)

Breaking it down step by step:

1. `S.lower().split("force")`: take the string, unify to lowercase, split into substrings separated by `"force"`
2. `s.replace("first","force")for s in <STEP 1>`: Replace all `"first"`'s with `"force"`
3. `` _`.join("first".join(<STEP 2>)`[2::5]`_ ``: replace all `"force"`'s with `"first"` by recombining the `"force"` delineated substrings with `"first"` and rejoin into single string (underscores added to get tick marks correct)
4. `zip(<STEP 3>,[(2,1)[l.isupper()]for l in S])`: zip each character of replaced phrase with case encoding of original string (2 for lowercase, 1 for uppercase)
5. `` _`[(t[0],t[0].upper())[t[1]==1]for t in <STEP 4>]`[2::5]`_ ``: Restore original casing, converts list to string (underscores added to get tick marks correct)

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by encoding upper as True and lower as False: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RY5NC8IwDIbv@xWhpxZKUcHLYEe9Cu5YCtatZZW6ljYy8M/PdijmkI@XPHmz2s7r533U0Lc3SVHuFK9JvGI0iTImUe6VsiEBgpvh7SIlRDyCmymxLmX8DlkkE70ezE/mpECDIayyubK98GGpR0WO3iH9LTDGpRcufy2hAn4DFFM3eWjbo1p76ECScyVsuJZ0ScOpmOBU3SBY2K5lwmHTRkBT9EFnA4vDKbwQTKkmwRLSSFTz/6ttoERMbkawNDNe9K4rbR3Y@gE "Python 2 – TIO Nexus")

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##RU8xbsMwDNzzCoKTGAgaMgbQ2K4B6jHN4MgSokC1BImB7X7eodMA5UAeD0fcsSx8y@NhDfZ7Tf3Pdeih07PFEGtj1IugXJ3HI6K55zgqddg7Mhw5eUVnNrGlPPmq6CJC5TRTHOE3FjX/6ZupvqTeeTXrhUQDDUTRmfeZaSVFVguR7ojWDiyc8XPzDPlL2qm6D9TIty0Q5ACvPA01vLgB2Avv@uZhivLLg8HL9BWmXAe87P4tjzuQKjWODEE10sJbK3BbaH0C "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Flex (lexer), 72 bytes

```
%%
 #define x(a) yytext[a]^=
(?i:first|force) x(1)6;x(3)16;x(4)17;ECHO;
```

To compile and run:

```
flex first.l
gcc lex.yy.c -lfl # -ll on Macs, apparently
./a.out
```

Comment: `first.l:3: EOF encountered inside an action` (oh, nevermind: it requires a newline at the end)

Comment: `ld: library not found for -lfl` (oh never mind, command is `gcc lex.yy.c -ll` on macOS)

Comment: Tested and approved.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 171 bytes

I wanted to try to do this using built-ins, but it can't beat the messy method with all the splitting and zipping.

```
import re,string as g
def f(s):f="istISTECOeco";l=re.split("(first|force)",s,0,re.IGNORECASE);l[1::2]=[t.translate(g.maketrans(f,f[::-1]))for t in l[1::2]];print"".join(l)
```

I think it's pretty clear what I'm doing here. Split the string on instances of first and force (case-insensitive), replace those instances with versions translated using str.translate, and join it back into a string again.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LY4xa8MwFIT3/oqHJglUE6ebjIcS3JIlgSSbY4Jw3nPVKpKRXsjS/@46pjd8cBx33ORuY0wMCXXm5MIANsPwckUCklkZqoXLvD2ems0e@ygqXycs8ugdSyHJpcy/FFOPSuisV3oOt5@7/aHZvB8bVfm2NGbd1S0XnGzI3jLKobjZH1y8JE2tMa9lp9Q8AwwuwH@pq8b5EAtRfEcXpFcTyWQfFxfGO0ulpvN9NWthuXC98I2/ED7ioUeIBE/zvHn6Aw)

Comment: Further golfing and switching to Python 3.8 brings it down to [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY49C8IwFEV3f0XolEAtrV0kIA6i4CRot7ZDWhMabD54eR0E/3u0wTscuIc7XP/Gydl67yGqQxdnYYanIIGDLMIy0IweNVcaAn6Ug1GyLP9PDDdt2RcIwoZZoKQBoTDiJZOhyA@ZDnh9NOfTTY4uy7HlfFv1jOWBbbTxDpCAjB60Raqotn5ByhiL3VL@klgl7hJrnCS5uPsoiVNkLeuv5gs "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: @movatica yes that's a much smarter way to go about it

Comment: You can update your post accordingly :)

Comment: @movatica no thanks. that's your solution. post it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>113</s> 102 bytes

*-11 bytes thanx to naffetS*

```python
lambda s:re.sub("(?i:first|force)",lambda m:m[0].translate(' tf Io RCE i  rceS TF  Os'*9),s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY09C8IwFAB3f8WjSxMpRXDRgjiIgU6Ftps6pJrQQPPBy@sg@N@jLa7HcRfeNHq3PwRM@nRPk7TDS0KsUJVxHljGzqbSBiN9tMen4lnxV2xlb7tHSShdnCQplgNpqD20lysYgJ/cQS8Amphvj7yIfGNs8EiAKgU0jphmxoWZGOc80ahgPYhmCXgNK1nOom67/gs)

*Inspired by [quintopias answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118575/86751).*

Comment: [102](https://tio.run/##LY09C8IwFAB3f8WjSxMpRXDRgjiIgU6Ftps6pJrQQPPBy@sg@N@jLa7HcRfeNHq3PwRM@nRPk7TDS0KsUJVxHljGzqbSBiN9tMen4lnxV2xlb7tHSShdnCQplgNpqD20lysYgJ/cQS8Amphvj7yIfGNs8EiAKgU0jphmxoWZGOc80ahgPYhmCXgNK1nOom67/gs)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `r`, <s>21 20 19</s> 18 bytes

```
⇩1∆o‛°⇩"JḂǓ"ƛ÷V;•F
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBciIsIiIsIuKHqTHiiIZv4oCbwrDih6lcIkrhuILHk1wixpvDt1Y74oCiRiIsIiIsIlwiRm9yY2Vmb1JjZWZPcmNFXCJcblwiRmlyc3RmaVJzdGZJcnNUXCJcblwidGhpcnN0cyBvZiBmaXJzdHNcIiJd)

Neat. String compression helps here but honestly the hard part was figuring out how to set up the lists with minimal repetition.

-1 because I never actually use the register in my final answer

-1 by switching the last two elements to remove the duplication

-1 again for redoing how the lists are created

```
⇩1∆o‛°⇩"JḂǓ"ƛ÷V;•F­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
 1∆o                # ‎⁡"first"
    ‛°⇩             # ‎⁢"force"
⇩      "J           # ‎⁣pair the two and append the lowercase input
         Ḃ          # ‎⁤push ["force", "first", input] and its reverse
          Ǔ         # ‎⁢⁡rotate the reverse so its in the order ["first", "force", input]
           "        # ‎⁢⁢pair the two
            ƛ  ;    # ‎⁢⁣map over each list
             ÷V     # ‎⁢⁤replacement of first/force
                •F  # ‎⁣⁡copy capitalization of input and remove the one identical to the input
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: Here comes a new challenger! Good job.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle [inputs containing both first and force](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBciIsIiIsIuKHqTHiiIZv4oCbwrDih6lcIkrhuILHk1wixpvDt1Y74oCiRiIsIiIsIlwidGhlIEZvcmNlIG9mIHRoZSBmaXJzVFwiIl0=)? [here](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBIiwiIiwiYM67wrJ8wrDih6lgOseNwr3Coz/ih6niiazCpeG4gsS/w7jhuZkk4oCiIiwiIiwiXCJGb3JjZWZvUmNlZk9yY0VcIlxuXCJGaXJzdGZpUnN0Zklyc1RcIlxuXCJ0aGlyc3RzIG9mIGZpcnN0c1wiXG5cInRoZSBGb3JjZSBvZiB0aGUgZmlyc1RcIiJd)'s a 21 that works

Comment: [actually 19 by porting osabie](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oep4oCbwrDih6kv4oCbzrvCsuKAm8Kw4oepdlbigJvOu8KyaiTigKIiLCIiLCJcIkZvcmNlZm9SY2VmT3JjRVwiXG5cIkZpcnN0ZmlSc3RmSXJzVFwiXG5cInRoaXJzdHMgb2YgZmlyc3RzXCJcblwidGhlIEZvcmNlIG9mIHRoZSBmaXJzVFwiIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## C# 273 bytes

```
string c(string s){var x=s.ToLower();int i=x.IndexOf("force")+1,j=x.IndexOf("first")+1,t=i>0&j>i?0:j>0?1:0;return i>0|j>0?s.Substring(0,t>0?(i=j):i)+(char)(s[i++]-(t>0?-6:6))+s[i++]+(char)(s[i++]+(t>0?-16:16))+(char)(s[i++]+(t>0?-15:15))+c(s.Length>i?s.Substring(i):""):s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cs-mono#jVJNi8IwEL37K4YeloRqaXfRQ0v1IC4UFKEV9uB6qDW1U9xmSVI/cP3tbj@0rLBgcxgy772ZTF4S7UIpYXbuAEgVKozgKpXAbAsRuW0kPe9DAUdXGgs@5QcmCHUwU4Du0fCyDTvOY6LFXERMo7rVTR9gFFJVsHJxaL6kQxyZdjo0R5ZtOoKpXGRQED8lJI0gX9enErOrCoSgm1IbqU6iJBSUyCXq@qpHSq43sAeU6jX0KNBrgTWwrVLyL9e3rX7BFdc0pizbqqSY7O8ASG1No7Z0LleA73y9K7y5WbTnuIFZiNnNouUKQlpaCBCcpGJfxphnku@Y8SFQsSlmjEREe68tos5zZe1aC2XM/ZY9Y/Tb9pyLaNJO6Qm5aKX8zM1iVdGq4msV31TCoPIFeAxlUn6Ydi1n4ampULBmcECVwInnbaqf1Lc4flGWeiJQ98mrR2uuMffHk4bx/GDRJNwf31/s0rlcfwE)

Direct port of [Kevin Cruijssen's Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118234/44998), turns out when it comes to getting the char in a string at a given index, C# is much golfier than java (`s[i++]` instead of `s.charAt(i++)`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 41 bytes

```
r"first|force"_d"i1o s1c t1e"¸m²®+ZuÃq}'i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@1@klJZZVFxSk5ZflJyqFJ@ilGmYr1BsmKxQYpiqdGhH7qFNh9ZpR5Uebi6sVc/8/1@pJCNVwQ2kViE/TQHEAWkPUQIA)

This would be considerably shorter if Japt had a sane transliterate function...

Alternate version:

```
r"first|force"_d"io sc te"¸®¬¸²Ã®+ZuÃq}'i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@1@klJZZVFxSk5ZflJyqFJ@ilJmvUJysUJKqdGjHoXWH1gDJTYebD63Tjio93FxYq575/79SSUaqghtIvUJ@mgKIAzIiRAkA)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 234 bytes

```cs
string a(string s){var l=s.ToLower();int f=l.IndexOf("first"),F=l.IndexOf("force"),m=f<F&f>-1?f:F>-1?F:f;return ++m>0?s.Substring(0,m)+(char)(s[m]^6)+s[m+1]+(char)(s[m+2]^16)+(char)(s[m+3]^17)+(s.Length-m>5?a(s.Substring(m+4)):""):s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJRa8IwEH7frzj6MBqqxermoJ36IBYERWgLe3AVak1soE1GkupE/O1dW7W4J5uHS@7Ld3f57hLLbsYZL@I0khKW5xcAqSJFYyikEpTtIdJvB4nOh0hAOpJmwBf8iIWOHMoUkFFqztkO/66IrhEqpNJQx/0HchHjEsxG5NN9JeOuNSG2W22uTRyBVS4YGEY27k2k6efba0W918mQocdJJJAu11m4GSKj3A0rfECNfrixho88Y1AiHyUizQVme5V0s/H7pNTxkDoz3hCyNQ3Z0rkUAD/5Ni1F37QfON3BMqLspn0dVurL3gD4J6lwZk45kzzF5pegCi8ow3qka@5VJnKeM69dasEk3GuZk1Cvbc6ViGftmHMhg1bM77xXrtpate3XdqASDHVfgBOonOqDtEu5jE5NhIIthiNVCZx43ib6SXyL8kEVOhe@ur@8HlojY@VNZ83N3PODxuHe9D6xy8ul@AM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
gsub(/first|force/i){$&.tr(s="iIsStTEeCcOo",s.reverse)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1YsKk2qVNAt@J9eXJqkoZ@WWVRcUpOWX5Scqp@pWa2ipldSpFFsq5TpWRxcEuKa6pzsn6@kU6xXlFqWWlScqln7/z9YsUJJRqqCm2dQcIiCG4jvllkUXKIANA1onAJQhbMrAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
„€Û‹›#`UVlY¡XY:Xý¹.Ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//@KAnuKCrMOb4oC54oC6I2BVVmxZwqFYWTpYw73CuS7Dj///Rmlyc3Rmb1JjZWZJcnNU//8)

I could not figure out a way of doing this shorter without using variables, so here we are.  I'm sure someone more versed with stack manipulation can figure it out

How?

```
„€Û‹›#`UVlY¡XY:Xý¹.Ï
„€Û‹›#`UV               X = "first" Y="force"
         l              Lower case the input
          Y¡            Split on "force"
            XY:         Replace "first" with "force"
               Xý       Join on "first"
                 ¹.Ï    Apply capitalization of input
```

Comment: Thanks, and good job on the split-replace-join. You're on second place after Vyxal currently.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>127</s> <s>247</s> <s>225</s> <s>219</s> 208 bytes

```swift
var b="force",c="first",a=b,d=a,x={(a=$0,d=$3,($1+"").lowercased().ranges(of:$2+"").map{a.replaceSubrange($0,with:zip(d,a[$0]).map{$1.isLowercase ?$0:.init($0.uppercased())})},a).3},f={x(x($0,$0,b,c),$0,c,b)}
```

Built and tested with Swift 5.9, so TIO is out of the window. [Here's a JDoodle link instead.](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Yg1)

---

**The following explanation is outdated, and refers to [this similar, yet slightly less complicated version](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/XzV):**

```swift
let f={let b="force",c="first",s=$0+"",x={var a=$0+"",d=$2+""
s.lowercased().ranges(of:$1+"").map{a.replaceSubrange($0,with:zip(d,a[$0]).map{$1.isLowercase ?$0:.init($0.uppercased())})}
return a}
return x(x(s,b,c),c,b)}
```

The current revision isn't much different in principle; the major differences are:

- Tuples are exploited to allow for one-line closures, which lets us use implicit `return` statements.
- All declarations are merged into a single `var` statement.
- The `s` variable is no longer used, and has been replaced with an extra parameter to `x`.
- Empty strings used for type inference have been replaced with references to other strings; this saves a byte wherever it's used.

---

With whitespace restored:

```swift
let f = {
  let b = "force", c = "first", s = $0 + "", x = {
    var a = $0 + "", d = $2 + ""
    s.lowercased().ranges(of: $1 + "").map {
      a.replaceSubrange($0, with: zip(d, a[$0]).map {
        $1.isLowercase ? $0 : .init($0.uppercased())
      })
    }
    return a
  }
  return x(x(s, b, c), c, b)}
```

### Explanation

There's a lot to follow here, so I'll try and step you through the least Swifty Swift code I've ever written. Knowledge of Swift's intricacies is invaluable in understanding this gibberish.

> Fair warning: Most of the identifiers used here are completely arbitrary.

#### Line 1

```swift
let f = { /* ... */ }
```

Since function declarations are generally not small, I've opted for a closure instead, so that the compiler can infer the parameter and return types. Plus, this means we don't have any pesky argument labels to deal with.

#### Line 2

```swift
let b = "force", c = "first", s = $0 + "", x = { /* ... */ }
```

`b` and `c` are simply there to shave off a few bytes, since I use each of those strings twice.

`s` serves a dual purpose. It lets me use the closure parameter (the original string) inside of more closures, since implicit closure parameters can only be used one level deep; and concatenating `""` to it lets the type checker know that it's a `String`, meaning I don't have to specify that directly.

`x` is simply another closure definition. It takes three parameters:

- the string to replace characters in
- the search string
- the replacement string

#### Line 3

```swift
var a = $0 + "", d = $2 + ""
```

`a` is there so I have a mutable copy of the string to work with. I also use the trick I used with `s` above to help out the type checker.

`d` serves the same purpose as `s` above (except for it being used differently, of course).

#### Line 4

```swift
s.lowercased().ranges(of: $1 + "").map { /* ... */ }
```

This lowercases the original string (to effectively make the substring search case insensitive) before finding all ranges containing the search string (`$1`, with `""` appended to assist the type checker). These ranges allow us to refer to discovered words in the string even after we start replacing them.

The call to `map` here serves the same purpose as a `for`-`in` loop, just with less bytes (and a warning since we don't use the result -- if you don't want a warning, replace `map` with `forEach`).

#### Line 5

```swift
a.replaceSubrange($0, with: zip(d, a[$0]).map { /* ... */ }
```

This line does the actual replacing. In this method call, `$0` is one of the ranges containing a word we want to replace. `a[$0]` gets the actual contents of the string in that range.

> `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` unfortunately does not have a non-`mutating` counterpart, which is why we declare `a` above as a `var` instead of a `let`.

The call to `zip` allows us to iterate over the original string and the replacement string simultaneously, allowing us to keep case unchanged. Speaking of which...

#### Line 6

```swift
$1.isLowercase ? $0 : .init($0.uppercased())
```

Here, `$1` is a character from the original string, and `$0` is the corresponding character from the replacement string.

- If `$1` is lowercase, we return `$0` unchanged (since I hardcoded the replacement strings to be lowercase).
- If `$1` is uppercase (or if it isn't cased at all), we return the result of uppercasing `$0` (if it isn't cased, this call does nothing).

> We have to wrap the call to `uppercased()` in a call to `Character.init(_:)` since `uppercased()` on `Character` returns a `String` (blame Swift's Unicode support).

#### Line 9

```swift
return a
```

The only line of this program that actually makes sense.

#### Line 11

```swift
return x(x(s, b, c), c, b)
```

> Remember: `b == "force"`, and `c == "first"`.

- We call our closure with the original string first, telling it to replace `"force"` with `"first"`.
- We then call the closure again with the result, and replace `"first"` with `"force"`.

  > We avoid replacing words we've already replaced by referencing the original, unmodified string when finding ranges.
- Finally, we return the result of *that* and leave the miniature catastrophe that is the `f` closure.

### But why, tho?

I've probably overcomplicated a good chunk of this program, but if we're being honest here, Swift was not designed with code golfing in mind. Still, that's what makes golfing fun in the first place!

Comment: I'd also specify that this is Swift 5 (since TIO is currently only supporting Swift 4).

Answer (score 0):

**C# (269 Bytes)**

```
string s(string z){var u=z.ToUpper();var a=new[]{"FIRST","FORCE"};return String.Join("",u.Split(a,StringSplitOptions.None).Aggregate((c,n)=>c+(u.Substring(c.Length,5)==a[0]?a[1]:a[0])+n).Select((c,i)=>Char.IsLower(z[i])?Char.ToLower(c):c));}
```

yet another c# solution, only the second-smallest because I declared two variables and so can't use lambda syntax. oh well, I had fun. :)

explanation:

- upshift the original string, then split on "FORCE" and "FIRST".
- aggregate
  the results and on every split, find the five-character substring that was used to split the original string using the length so far of the string being
  aggregated. if it was "force" make it "first" and vice versa
- select all the characters of the newly created all caps string and
  check if the original string was lowercase at the same index. if yes, return lowercased character at that index in the new string, otherwise return the uppercase character